How do i iteratively traverse directory and parse it into struct in rust?
with some help, i was able to traverse directory and parse it into Collection struct recursively like this
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Collection {
    pub relative_path: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub collections: Vec<Collection>,
    pub requests: Vec<Request>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Request {
    pub relative_path: String,
    pub name: String,
}

fn build_collection_from_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Collection {
    let path = path.as_ref();
    let name = path.file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy().into_owned();
    let relative_path = path.to_string_lossy().into_owned();

    let mut collection = Collection {
        relative_path: relative_path.clone(),
        name,
        collections: vec![],
        requests: vec![],
    };

    if let Ok(entries) = fs::read_dir(path) {
        for entry in entries {
            if let Ok(entry) = entry {
                let entry_path = entry.path();
                if entry_path.is_dir() {
                    // It's a folder, add as a sub-collection
                    collection
                        .collections
                        .push(build_collection_from_path(entry_path));
                } else if entry_path.is_file() {
                    // It's a file, add as a request
                    let file_name = entry_path
                        .file_name()
                        .unwrap()
                        .to_string_lossy()
                        .into_owned();
                    let file_relative_path = entry_path.to_string_lossy().into_owned();
                    collection.requests.push(Request {
                        relative_path: file_relative_path,
                        name: file_name,
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    collection
}

// Function to traverse both root folders (collections) and root-level files (requests)
fn bfs_traverse_folders_and_files<P: AsRef<Path>>(root_path: P) -> (Vec<Collection>, Vec<Request>) {
    let root_path = root_path.as_ref();

    // Initialize the root collections and requests
    let mut root_collections: Vec<Collection> = Vec::new();
    let mut root_requests: Vec<Request> = Vec::new();

    // Traverse the root directory
    if let Ok(entries) = fs::read_dir(root_path) {
        for entry in entries {
            if let Ok(entry) = entry {
                let entry_path = entry.path();
                if entry_path.is_dir() {
                    // Create and push the folder as a collection
                    let collection = build_collection_from_path(entry_path);
                    root_collections.push(collection);
                } else if entry_path.is_file() {
                    // Push the file as a request
                    let file_name = entry_path
                        .file_name()
                        .unwrap()
                        .to_string_lossy()
                        .into_owned();
                    let file_relative_path = entry_path.to_string_lossy().into_owned();
                    root_requests.push(Request {
                        relative_path: file_relative_path,
                        name: file_name,
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    (root_collections, root_requests)
}


    let (root_collections_recursive, root_requests_recursive) =
        bfs_traverse_folders_and_files(root_path);

    println!(
        "Root Collections Recursive:\n{:#?}",
        root_collections_recursive
    );
    println!("Root Requests Recursive:\n{:#?}", root_requests_recursive);

but i'm unable to do this iteratively and assign collections properly
for iterative approach i was thinking of using a stack vector and then keeping a mutable ref to the collection but i can't get it to compile because i cannot seem to share a mutable reference
if i slap a .clone() to it then it doesn't translate to the struct properly because i copied over the contents early? is there a way to get around it please help.
Edit:
i was able to do this iteratively but i had to use unsafe in order to mutate the parent collection, not sure if it could be done in a better way. i'll look into RefCell as well as suggested by @cafce25
here's the code
// Function to iteratively build the Collection structure
fn build_collection_from_path_iterative<P: AsRef<Path>>(root_path: P) -> Collection {
    let root_path = root_path.as_ref();
    let root_name = root_path
        .file_name()
        .unwrap()
        .to_string_lossy()
        .into_owned();
    let root_relative_path = root_path.to_string_lossy().into_owned();

    let mut root_collection = Collection {
        relative_path: root_relative_path.clone(),
        name: root_name,
        collections: vec![],
        requests: vec![],
    };

    // Stack to simulate DFS, storing (current path, pointer to parent collection)
    let mut stack: Vec<(PathBuf, *mut Collection)> = Vec::new();
    stack.push((
        root_path.to_path_buf(),
        &mut root_collection as *mut Collection,
    ));

    while let Some((current_path, parent_collection_ptr)) = stack.pop() {
        if let Ok(entries) = fs::read_dir(&current_path) {
            for entry in entries {
                if let Ok(entry) = entry {
                    let entry_path = entry.path();
                    let parent_collection = unsafe { &mut *parent_collection_ptr }; // Dereference the raw pointer to modify parent

                    if entry_path.is_dir() {
                        // Create sub-collection for directory
                        let sub_collection_name = entry_path
                            .file_name()
                            .unwrap()
                            .to_string_lossy()
                            .into_owned();
                        let sub_collection = Collection {
                            relative_path: entry_path.to_string_lossy().into_owned(),
                            name: sub_collection_name,
                            collections: vec![],
                            requests: vec![],
                        };

                        // Push the sub-collection into the parent collection's `collections` vector
                        parent_collection.collections.push(sub_collection);

                        // Push the new sub-collection onto the stack for further traversal
                        let sub_collection_ptr =
                            parent_collection.collections.last_mut().unwrap() as *mut Collection; // Get a pointer to the last added collection
                        stack.push((entry_path.clone(), sub_collection_ptr));
                    } else if entry_path.is_file() {
                        // Add file as a request
                        let file_name = entry_path
                            .file_name()
                            .unwrap()
                            .to_string_lossy()
                            .into_owned();
                        let file_relative_path = entry_path.to_string_lossy().into_owned();
                        parent_collection.requests.push(Request {
                            relative_path: file_relative_path,
                            name: file_name,
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    root_collection
}


"i cannot seem to share a mutable reference" yes, that's why they are often called exclusive references, and that's a more accurate description. You probably want to use a RefCell

I'm confused by your description why would an iterative BFS need to share anything? In a loop you pop a path from the stack, push files to the results, and push new dir entries back on the stack, what sharing is there?

@Masklinn i need to update the parent collection that's why i need to share the reference and update it. i've updated my post, i was able to do it iteratively but i had to use unsafe
